# What is equivalent to inf files on Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, inf

So as I said in the title, what is equivalent to inf files on Mac(if something like that exist)?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't belong on SO

Comment: Do you mean .inf for autorun ?

Comment: @Luca .inf for driver installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest thing to .inf Windows driver files in MAC OSX are kexts (Kernel Extension)

[Here you can find more info on kexts](http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/01/what-are-kexts.html)

Comment: So .plist file in a Xcode project is completely different that a .inf file in visual studio project(in driver development)? Why do we need the .plist files? Thanks

Comment: A kexts need its own .plist file, take a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/Articles/infoplist_keys.html